# Bootstrap navbar doesnt collapse and is not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi first I am a very beginner. 
I m trying to create a responsive navbar with bootstrap but It is not reponsive at all.

- The navbar does not collapse my elements.
- Elements are not aligned center, in the navbar
- I setted a container-fluid and my elements doesnt spread as it shoud.
- I would like that only my navlinks show when I click on the burger menu.

I m completely lost .`Can someone plz help me...
thanks

````
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="navbar" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid nav-fill">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light d-flex justify-content-center" role="navigation">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent"
            aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex align-items-center justify-content-lg-between " id="navbarContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 d-flex align-items-center"> 
              <li class="nav-item">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill d-flex align-items-center">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="brand-logo navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="sr-logo" src="./img/sr-logo.png"
                      alt="sr-logo.png"></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="brand-logo-user navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="lvmh-logo" src="./img/lvmh-logo.jpg"
                      alt="lvmh-logo.jpg"></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item w-50">
                <ul class="navlinks navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">LINK1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK4</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item align-items-center ml-5">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill align-items-center">
                  <li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <img src="img/profil.svg" class="profile d-inline">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <p class="username d-inline ml-3">Mr. Blah</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill d-flex justify-content-between w-75">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="language active d-inline">FR</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class=" language d-inline">EN<a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li> 
          </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>```




My CSS :

    ```body{
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }

    nav{
      background-color: white;
      height: 97px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .brands {
      display: inline;  
      align-items: center;
    }
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: black;
    }

    .navlinks{
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      text-align: center;
      color: black
    }
    .navlinks li > a:after{
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 5px;
      background-color:#00e7b5;
      border-radius: 7%;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
    .navlinks li > a:hover:after{
      transform: scaleX(1);
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
    .navlinks .active{
      color:#00e7b5 !important;
    }


    img{
      max-width: 150px;
      max-height: 20px;
    }


    .username{
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      text-align: center;
      color: #5300b4;
    }

    .language{
      font-family: Poppins;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      color: black;
    }


    .navlinks a:hover{
      color: #00e7b5 !important;
      }
    nav ul{
        text-align: center;
      }```
````

Comment: Why are you using both v3 and v4 of bootstrap in your project ?

Comment: Cause I m totally in panic sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

First remove all the instances of BS v3 and just add the CDN's for BS v4, make sure to add CSS links in header and JS links before closing body tag. 
You can get the latest CDN's from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/), please make sure to include jquery and popper.js before adding bootstrap js as BS4 depends upon these two scripts, you can find these script CDN's on same link, then

You have to align you content correctly as currently it is not, read more about bootstrap navbar [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp) and now coming to the pointers in you query

**The navbar does not collapse my elements.** 
After using the correct CDN's at right place it will start collapsing.

**Elements are not aligned center, in the navbar** 
From above link see how to make navbar content centered.

**I setted a container-fluid and my elements doesnt spread as it shoud.**
It will work, also make sure not to use `container-fluid` inside `container-fluid` as it will add unnecessary padding from both sides.

**I would like that only my navlinks show when I click on the burger menu.**
To get this result move your `<a class="brand-logo navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="sr-logo" src="./img/sr-logo.png" alt="sr-logo.png"></a>` outside the div with class `collapse`.

Please check you code thoroughly as it contains many tags which are not opened or closed at correct places, try to make the navbar from starting and it will work.

Good luck, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the navbar toggle

```
body{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
margin-left:100px;
margin-right:100px;
}

.brands {
  display: inline;  
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: black;
}

.navlinks{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black
}
.navlinks li > a:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color:#00e7b5;
  border-radius: 7%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.navlinks li > a:hover:after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.navlinks .active{
  color:#00e7b5 !important;
}

img{
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 20px;
}

.username{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #5300b4;
}

.language{
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: black;
}

.navlinks a:hover{
  color: #00e7b5 !important;
}
nav ul{
    text-align: center;
}

    <body>
<br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="brand-logo navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="sr-logo" src="./img/sr-logo.png">Brand </a>
  
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navlinks">

          <li><a class="nav-link"  href="#">LINK1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LINK2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LINK3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LINK4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navlinks">
          <a class="brand-logo navbar-brand username" href="#"><img class="sr-logo" src="./img/1.jpg">Mr X</a>
        
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
    </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

header files:
I've used bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```